# Read one column from csv and make new column with previous column data

Tags: ruby, string, csv

In "id" column in source image, first number before "-" id chapter number in target image and after "-" that is verse in target image. In verse I am creating chunk of data from after "-". I tried with few line bit not understanding how I should move ahead.

> I need to read this [source column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuCOE.png) data from csv file.
>
> And want to make this format [target column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBGKF.png)

```
chapter = []
verse = []
CSV.foreach('test_file.csv') do |row|   
 if (row[3] != "id" && row[3] != nil)
    chapter << row[3].partition("-").first
    verse << row[3].partition("-").last
 end
end
```

Comment: Why "01 09-12"?  Shouldn't it be "01 09-11" and "01 12-99" ?

Comment: From source image column "id" has first number is chapter and second is for chunk like: 01-01 in first row and 01-04 is second column. And then first 01 from both row is chapter that will store in separate column. and second 01 from first row and 04 from second row will store as chunk one less than first like 01-03 in separate column.

Answer (score 0):

## I have wrote answer below.

> I am reading csv file with same content.

```
chapter = []
verse = []
temp = []
pos = 0

CSV.foreach("test_file.csv") do |row|
    puts row
    if (row[1] != "id" && row[1] != nil)
        chapter << row[1].partition("-").first
        if(temp.size>0)
            no = row[1].partition("-").last
            verse_no = (no.to_i - 1)
            updated_verse = verse_no < 10 ? "0"+verse_no.to_s : verse_no.to_s
            verse.insert(pos, temp[pos]+ "-" + updated_verse)
            temp << no
            pos = pos + 1
        else
            temp << row[1].partition("-").last
        end
    end
end
puts verse
puts chapter
```